# Are longer wavelength flash "fuzzy" ? (Feynman lecture Vol 3 chap 1)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, double-slit-experiment, wavelength

I am reading Feynman lecture volume 3 , Chapter 1.
https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/III_01.html#Ch1-S8
(search "fuzzy" in page to find the concerning paragraph.)
I'll quote the relevant part:

> You remember that when we discussed the microscope we pointed out that, due to the wave nature of the light, there is a limitation on how close two spots can be and still be seen as two separate spots. This distance is of the order of the wavelength of light. So now, when we make the wavelength longer than the distance between our holes, we see a big fuzzy flash when the light is scattered by the electrons. We can no longer tell which hole the electron went through! We just know it went somewhere!

My question is suppose if our electron gun fires an electron at a time  would the flash still be fuzzy? Because Feynman seems to point Rayleigh criterion but that need *two* sources of light and here we have only one the (electron sending off Compton scattered photon). \

**Edit**
Bit more context  is this. Basically I am wondering why can't we use longer wavelength light to detect electron . And the para quoted in question is the reason Feynman gives.